# Не подключились шрифты на хостинге

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Доброго времени! Не могу понять почему при заливе на хостинг отключились подключенные шрифты! На локальном хостинге все отлично а вот на сервере провайдера на сайте [kelzin.kz](http://kelzin.kz) все скатилось к стандартным Таймс, вроде уже и во всех форматах шрифты определил вот так:

```
@font-face
 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed Light';
 src: url('open-sans-cond-light_allfont.ru-webfont.eot');
src: url('open-sans-cond-light_allfont.ru-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('open-sans-cond-light_allfont.ru-webfont.svg#open_sanscondensed_light') format('svg'),
     url('open-sans-cond-light_[allfont.ru].ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('open-sans-cond-light_allfont.ru-webfont.woff') format('woff');
 }
 @font-face
{
   font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
src: url('open-sans-condensed-bold_allfont.ru_0-webfont.eot');
src: url('open-sans-condensed-bold_allfont.ru_0-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('open-sans-condensed-bold_allfont.ru_0-webfont.svg#open_sans_condensedbold') format('svg'),
     url('open-sans-condensed-bold_[allfont.ru]_0.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('open-sans-condensed-bold_allfont.ru_0-webfont.woff')   format('woff');
    }
```

даже учел что некоторые хосты чувствительны к реестру расширения шрифта (.OTF и .otf) все равно не могу понять в чем дело, подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Попроще имена файлов со шрифтами сделайте.

Comment: Ошибки в консоле видели? Предположу, что проблема в путях!

Comment: Поместите файлы шрифтов в ту же папку что и файл css или пропишите правильные пути к ним.

Comment: @Visman ваш совет помог конвертируйте его пожалуйста в ответ что бы я мог закрыть статистику